# RDS Amazon reconhece o horario brasileiro como Manaus UTC-04:00 e não Brasilia UTC-03:00

Tags: sql-server, amazon-aws

Estou começando a utilizar os serviços AWS e me deparei com um "problema" na Amazon RDS. Utilizo Sql Server e o mesmo atualiza sua hora de acordo com a hora do servidor, porém quando seleciono o horário referente a minha *time zone* UTC-03:00(greenland no servidor da RDS) ele não reconhece o horário de verão.

Nas documentações da AWS ele diz que essa *time zone* reconhece horários de verão. Se utilizo o *Brazilian Standard time*, ele até reconhece o horário de verão. porém eles utilizam Manaus como base o que deixa minha hora errada, pois estou no Rio de Janeiro e aqui nos baseamos por Brasilia UTC-03:00.

Alguém já teve este problema? Como resolveu?

Comment: Olá, veja se essa [documentação](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-change-time-zone/) te ajuda.

Comment: Danilo, obrigado pela resposta, mas eu ja vi esta documentação também. O problema que a zona que deveria compreender o Brasil ( central Brazilian Time) esta como amazonas o que não serve para quem mora na maior parte do Brasil que utiliza Brasilia como padrão. O padrão da amazon de UTC -03:00 que compreende o horario utilizado no Rio e em mais da metade dos estados brasileiros esta como Greenland e não aplica a mudança de horario o que deixa meu banco sempre uma hora atras.

Comment: Entendi. Tenho uma instância de mysql na região São Paulo que veio por default como UTC e está certinho com o horário de verão.

Comment: Altere seu timezone para GMT+2 no seu RDS Option groups caso seja postgresql, se for Mysql terá que colocar Brasil/East

Comment: -1 Como fazer isso? Como chegar nessa opção?  Falta muitos detalhes na sua resposta.

Comment: Isso é uma questão de suporte (configuração de servidor) que depende de peculiaridade do serviço contratado, não de programação. Pode ser feita em inglês no http://superuser.com ou http://serverfault.com De qualquer forma, os comentários continuam abertos para quem puder ajudar. Se dentro deste problema tiver alguma dúvida sobre uma determinada configuração específica de alguma ferramenta de uso comum [dentro do escopo](/help/on-topic) pode [edit] a questão focando só nisso (e postando todos os dados relevantes, como configuração atual) para a comunidade reavaliar.